# Should all reusable components implement Default Props?

Tags: reactjs

Just starting to learn React and was wondering if it's good practice to always implement default props for reusable components.

I can see it giving a clear advantage as anyone who wants to use this component will know exactly what props to pass to it in order to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to communicate to people using your component what properties are optional, i recommend doing so with prop types (and/or documentation and/or typescript). Default props on the other hand are most useful to the person *writing* the component, not those using it. Default props allow you to skip checks for `undefined`s, since they will have been filled in with default values

Comment: I hadn't learnt about PropTypes yet, thanks for the great answer. It cleared up a bunch of questions I had.